# Is it possible to build OpAmp circuit with "anisotropic" gain?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback

I was curious if it is possible to make OpAmp circuit with gain that is dependent on sign of dv/dt (k1 for rising voltage, k2 for falling)?

Comment: What would you expect to happen at that instant when the sign of dV/dt changes, when the voltage has been rising but then starts falling? What should happen if the input voltage is constant?

Comment: 1) output voltage jump 2) if assume that there are some noise fluctuation - random jump from Vo=k1*Vi and Vo=k2*Vi so Vo_avg=(k1+k2)/2*Vi

Comment: What is the source for dv/dt?

Comment: by v i mean V_in — input voltage for such circuit

Comment: Yes.  It is.  But that makes kind of a short answer.

Comment: let it be sine wave 1kHz in range 0..5 V

Comment: Soooo...like a PGA with two gains where the gain selection control is connected to the output of zero-comparator with a differentiator at the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best write down what you want:

$$V_{out}(t) = V_{in}(t) \cdot \begin{cases}
k_1 &\text{if}& \frac{\mathrm d V_{in}}{\mathrm d\,t} < 0\\
k_2 &\text{else}
\end{cases}\label1\tag1$$

So, all just standard things you can piece together. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications) even has nearly all these...

1. Build a *inverting differentiator* (standard opamp configuration, 1 capacitor, one resistor).
2. Build a comparator to convert sign to a maximally clear high or low.
3. use said high or low to activate an *analog switch IC*, power opamps of the gain you want, bias a PIN diode if you're working with RF,… to select an amplified version with the right gain.

> I was curious if it is possible to make OpAmp circuit with gain that is dependent on sign of dv/dt

Proof by examples: yes, it's possible, but since \$\eqref1\$ is a strongly nonlinear behaviour, it can't work with linear circuitry like capacitors, resistors and opamps alone. You need some nonlinear behaviour.

The question really is whether you **actually** want that. Sounds like a bad idea in any application I can think of. Your question is interesting as an electronics project in itself – but I almost guarantee you, whatever it is that you're going to build with it won't be very robust against noise, the output will be spectrally *most* surprising, and you'll be surprised how little you will actually enjoy the jumps in output voltage that you specified this way.

Comment: Could you expand on the nonlinearity of the differentiation operation?

Comment: the differentiation is the only thing that's linear.

Comment: "but since (1) is a strongly nonlinear behaviour...", Ah, the (1) is not referred to point (1) in your post, but to eq (1). I thought you were implying that D is not linear.